# Running git commands using subprocess.Popen in python

Tags: python, git, popen

I am writing a small python script that needs to execute git commands from inside a given directory

The code is as follows:

```
import subprocess, os

pr = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/git', 'status'],                  
       cwd=os.path.dirname('/path/to/dir/'), 
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
       stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
       shell=True)
(out, error) = pr.communicate()
print out
```

But it shows git usage as the output.

If the command doesn't involve git for eg. `['ls']` then it shows the correct output.

Is there anything I am missing ?

python version - 2.6.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On Unix, with `shell=True`: *[…]* If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional **arguments to the shell itself**.

You don't want `shell=True` and also a list of arguments. Set `shell=False`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I passed args as string. But still had to set `shell=True`. otherwise it raises `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: It's safer to pass variable arguments as a list, but if you have a fixed command, there's no harm in sending it through bash.